# Ng-grid get rid of cell padding

Tags: css, cell, margin, padding, ng-grid

So far I have tried to change the cell padding to 0, but ng-grid wants it to be 5 pixels.  I originally made a css class called test with the following definition

```
test {
    padding:0;
}
```

then i figured out that ng-grid is overriding it with the class called ngCellText so the only way to overwrite inline css is to add important

```
test{
    padding:0 !important;
}
```

and this didn't work either. By the way my jade (no bracket html)(it also has a little bootstrap) looks like this

```
div.test
    div.row-fluid.span12
        div(my ng-grid document)
```

so then, since that didn't work, I looked at cellTemplate.  Here is the default html for it

```
<div class="ngCellText ng-scope col0 colt0 (**input test class here**)" 
ng-class="col.colIndex()">
<span ng-cell-text="" class="ng-binding">***0***</span>
</div>
```

This is great and it gets rid of the padding, but as you can see "***0***" is hardcoded since this if from an inspected element using chrome.  How would I be able to do this using my ng-grid field?  Also, if you have any other ideas on how to fix this please feel free on pitching in.  Preferably I would like to get the !important working or anything else since the way I have ng-grid set up is so I can put it in different places of my website so custom css would be best!

Comment: Difficult to understand , why not to do simple `.ngCellText {padding: 0;}` ?

Comment: I appoligize for that, it has been even more confusing for me to wrap my head around this, but .ngCellText is in ng-grid.css which is kind of a hacky way of changing this, and it would effect my other grids that I want the 5px padding.

Comment: why not to put it in css file where you already putted your `test {    padding:0;}` so it will affect only this specific html page?

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, but I will do that since there really is no other way, thanks!  If you put that into a response I will give you the green check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help:

```
div.ngCellText[class*="col"] {
   padding: 0;
}
```

But seems you can just override it like this:

```
.ngCellText {padding: 0;}
```